# Accelerating 2D FFT(W) of C-contiguous, aligned array

Tags: python, memory-alignment, fftw, contiguous, pyfftw

I'm doing 2D FFTs of 2D arrays of complex numbers using pyFFTW. These arrays can get very large (~128 GiB), so execution time is crucial. (The background is wavefront propagation in optical physics.)

Have a look at the following toy code:

```
import numpy as np
import pyfftw
import multiprocessing


a = np.random.rand(16384, 16384) + 1j*np.random.rand(16384, 16384)

fft = pyfftw.FFTW(a, a, axes = (0, 1), direction = 'FFTW_FORWARD', flags = ('FFTW_ESTIMATE', 'FFTW_UNALIGNED', 'FFTW_DESTROY_INPUT',), threads = multiprocessing.cpu_count())
a = fft()
```

The FFT takes some seconds to execute on my modern 64-bit machine.

Both the result and the execution time remain the same when doing the 2D FFT in two steps (1D-FFTs of all columns and of all rows):

```
fft = pyfftw.FFTW(a, a, axes = (0,), direction = 'FFTW_FORWARD', flags = ('FFTW_ESTIMATE', 'FFTW_UNALIGNED', 'FFTW_DESTROY_INPUT',), threads = multiprocessing.cpu_count())
a = fft()
fft = pyfftw.FFTW(a, a, axes = (1,), direction = 'FFTW_FORWARD', flags = ('FFTW_ESTIMATE', 'FFTW_UNALIGNED', 'FFTW_DESTROY_INPUT',), threads = multiprocessing.cpu_count())
a = fft()
```

However, taking the time of these steps individually shows that **the column-FFT is roughly 10 times slower than the row-FFT**.

The reason, I guess, is the fact that the array is saved to physical RAM row by row. Indeed, a.flags gives

```
C_CONTIGUOUS : True
F_CONTIGUOUS : False
OWNDATA : True
WRITEABLE : True
ALIGNED : True
UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

while a.strides gives

```
(262144, 16)
```

So, the array is C-contiguous and seems to be correctly aligned. However, removing the flag 'FFTW_UNALIGNED' makes the column-FFT roughly another 10 times slower (while the row-FFT becomes slightly faster).

Hence, my questions is:

**Might there be something wrong with the alignment or is a 10 times slower access to columns than to rows for C-contiguous arrays the physical limit?**

*EDIT: Indeed, a factor of 10 seems to be too large. Let's compare simple read/write access of rows and columns:*

```
a[:,0:16384:2]*=1j
```

and

```
a[0:16384:2,:]*=1j
```

*Multiplying the columns with an even index (first variant) is about 2 times slower than multiplying the rows with an even index (second variant).*

*EDIT: The exact code entered in ipython is*

```
In [1]: import pyfftw

In [2]: import multiprocessing

In [3]: a = np.random.rand(16384, 16384) + 1j*np.random.rand(16384, 16384)

In [4]: fft = pyfftw.FFTW(a, a, axes = (0, 1), direction = 'FFTW_FORWARD', flags = ('FFTW_ESTIMATE', 'FFTW_UNALIGNED', 'FFTW_DESTROY_INPUT',), threads = multiprocessing.cpu_count())

In [5]: %timeit a = fft()
```

Comment: How are you measuring the time?

Comment: Your simple example is somewhat naive. In a simple loop the processor can prefetch easily and I would expect it to be doing that. In an FFT, this is less simple. I'd be interested to know what happens if you let FFTW work out the fastest 2D transform itself (by setting both axes).

Comment: Also, I reiterate the comment of @GavinPortwood: How are you measuring the time? There are various tunings you can do, such as making sure your data is _actually_ aligned and using the `FFTW_MEASURE` flag (once, and then storing the result).

Comment: @GavinPortwood: I'm measuring the time using the time()-method from the time module.

Comment: Further to my comments above, I don't get anything like your timing differences. Granted, that's with a 1GB array, but I'd be surprised if that's not about the same. For reference, for a 8192x8192 array I get about 280ms for the rows and 690ms for the cols. If I do it as a 2D array it's about 1.35s (which is curious in itself). Those numbers don't seem too odd to me. So, I reiterate, can you post the exact code you're using the estimate your timings?

Comment: @phlegmax you should be using `timeit` - rolling your own timing routine is quite problematic.

Comment: @HenryGomersall Indeed, using timeit I get slightly different values. For 8192x8192, I get 118 ms with (1,), 497 ms with (0,), and 609 ms with (0,1). So, here we have a factor of about 4. However, for 16384x16384 I get a factor of 7 and for 32768x32768 I get a factor of 7.5. Unlike in your case the time for the 2D transform is always roughly the sum of the separate transforms.

Comment: @HenryGomersall I haven't taken the time for larger arrays so far since this a very time consuming. For larger arrays I'm using memory maps. The FFT is then about a factor 2 slower (with an NVMe-SSD), but I still get a similar ratio for the execution times of row transforms and column transforms.

Comment: @phlegmax can you post your code?

Comment: @HenryGomersall What exactly do you mean by "actually aligned"? By the way, with 64-bit complex numbers (instead of 128-bit) the ratio inreases further to about 10. Still, a.flags and a.stride say that everything is contiguous and aligned (the second entry of the output of a.strides then reads 8 which makes sense, I guess).

Comment: @HenryGomersall By the way, I added the exact code to my post.

Comment: You can't infer alignment from strides (though to be aligned across all rows/cols, you need the strides to be right). Take a look at [the utility functions](http://pyfftw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/pyfftw/pyfftw.html#utility-functions).

Comment: Remove the `'FFTW_UNALIGNED'` flag. You basically should never use that if you want it to go fast. Turn on `'FFTW_MEASURE'` instead of `'FFTW_ESTIMATE'`and it might improve things a bit. Make sure your arrays are aligned using the [relevant utility function](http://pyfftw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/pyfftw/pyfftw.html#utility-functions) (you might need to roll your own if you're working on such large datasets). Using an in-place transform will also slow everything down.

Comment: Turning on FFTW_MEASURE reduces the execution time of the col-transform, while the row-transform remains unchanged. This way I get ratios of 2 (which seems reasonable) for small data sets to 6 for large data sets. Furthermore, indeed, pyfftw suggests a different byte length (32) for alignment than numpy (16). However, aligning the arrays with the pyfftw utility function and removing the FFTW_UNALIGNED flag doesn't improve execution time; instead it's getting slightly worse. Strange! Still I would suggest to accept Henry's last comment as an answer. Thank you, Henry!